# How do I fix the SQLState_42000?

Tags: sql-server, database, twincat

I'm following a YouTube tutorial on implementing a database into a TwinCAT project, but when I check the connection, I get this error:

[image]

I'm pretty certain I don't have any syntax errors since my SQL table executed fine and my MAIN PRG is empty, so that leaves an access violation. The problem is I have no idea why I'm getting that error since I followed every step up to that point.

Is there anything I'm missing or I did wrong?

Just in case, here is my code I used to generate the SQL table:

```
use TestDB;
create table TwinCATSQL (bundleID varchar(10), profileLength decimal, profileWidth decimal, profileHeight decimal, profileFlex decimal, pieces int,
bundleSizeX int, bundleSizeY int, bundleLevel int, destination int, manualRepackOnly bit);
select * from TwinCATSQL;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)a

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i struggled with the same problem and couldn't actually solve it yet, but i just used the "master" database to run tests with SQL, since it seems to be a problem with the user authentication. With the master database you just uncheck the Authentication Box and it shoul let you check the database with no problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that the user password needs changing:
when creating a user for the SQL server and assigning a password, it's actually a temporary password which will not allow automated log-ins.
Solution:

1. Use SSMS to log-in into the server. On welcome screen ("Connect to server") select "SQL Server Authentication" instead of the default "Windows Authentication".
2. Use the user credentials you created for accessing the SQL DB from TwinCAT.
3. If the user+password are correct, you'll be requested to select a new password and confirm it.
4. If you changed the password to something different from the original - update it on the TF6420 configurator as well!
5. Problem solved! Check with the "CHECK" button of the TF6420
   configurator.